# OxyPlot: How to use the axis label formatter and show Y labels?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, oxyplot

I'm using to Oxyplot for my Xamarin.iOS project for plotting a bar chart..

This is what my graph currently looks likes currently

[image]

here's instead of x axis values which are numbers, I want to show sun, mon true, wed.....

I can see that CategoryAxis has a method called LabelFormatter which returns `Func<double, string>`, but how do I use it?

And also why are the Y-Axis labels not showing?

```
public class MyClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the plot model that is shown in the demo apps.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>My model.</value>
    public PlotModel MyModel { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="OxyPlotSample.MyClass"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public MyClass()
    {

        var model = new PlotModel { Title = "ColumnSeries" };
        model.PlotAreaBorderColor = OxyColors.Transparent;
        // A ColumnSeries requires a CategoryAxis on the x-axis.

        model.Axes.Add(new CategoryAxis()
        {
            Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
            MinorTickSize = 0,
            MajorTickSize = 0,
            //MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid,
            //MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid,
        });

        model.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis()
        {
            AxislineStyle = LineStyle.None,
            Position = AxisPosition.Left,
            MinorTickSize = 0,
            MajorTickSize = 0,
            MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid,
            MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid,
            Minimum = 0,
            Maximum = 400,
        });

        var series = new ColumnSeries();
        series.Items.Add(new ColumnItem() { Value = 200, Color = OxyColors.Orange});
        series.Items.Add(new ColumnItem(200));
        series.Items.Add(new ColumnItem(300));
        series.Items.Add(new ColumnItem(100));
        series.Items.Add(new ColumnItem(200));
        series.Items.Add(new ColumnItem(100));
        series.Items.Add(new ColumnItem(130));

        model.Series.Add(series);

        this.MyModel = model;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To show the label on the axis you have to specify the property `MajorStep`, Oxyplot will paint only the labels matching the major step.

```
model.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis()
{
    MajorStep = 10,
    Position = AxisPosition.Left,
    ...
});
```

And to modify the labels with the day name, you can use a `DateTimeAxis` instead of `LinearAxis`:

```
model.Axes.Add(new DateTimeAxis()
{
    StringFormat = "ddd",
    Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
    ...
});
```

If you want something more customized you will have to use the `LabelFormatter` attribute.

**EDIT:**

Labels in CategoryAxis:

```
var categoryAxis = new CategoryAxis()
{
    Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
    ...
};

categoryAxis.ActualLabels.Add("Mon");
categoryAxis.ActualLabels.Add("Tue");
categoryAxis.ActualLabels.Add("Wed");
categoryAxis.ActualLabels.Add("Thu");
categoryAxis.ActualLabels.Add("Fri");
categoryAxis.ActualLabels.Add("Sat");
categoryAxis.ActualLabels.Add("Sun");

Model.Axes.Add(categoryAxis);
```

`CategoryAxis.ActualLabels` is readOnly, so you will have to Add the items one by one.

Comment: But, to plot a column series, don't I have to add a CategoryAxis() as the X Axis?

Comment: I've edited the answer, I think this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: thank you. that works. And I think you for about the second part of my quesiton.. To show the y levels. -_-

Comment: Currently, Y value 0 shows, next Y value is 500, which is can see only when I scroll up.. How can I show the Y values at each grid line???

Comment: Have you specified Major Step = 100? because I've tried it and it works. Maybe I didnt understand your issue, could you specify a little more?